# Banana ripeness - Python

Tags: python

I am starting to code on Python.
I am trying to study a code. When i try to run it:

**img_re = cv2.resize(img, (640,480)) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3)**
I dont know how to change it. Could someone help me?

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

def averagecolor(image):
    return np.mean(image, axis=(0, 1))
    (r"C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop/Banana_Ripeness-master/Data/haar_face_banana.xml")
    #(r"C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop/myac.csv")
path = (r"C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop/Banana_Ripeness-master/Data/")
trainX = []
trainY = []

for label in ('Unriped','Riped', 'No Banana Found'):
    print ("Loading training images for the label: "+label)
    
    #Load all images inside the subfolder
    for filename in os.listdir(path+label+"/"): 
        img = cv2.imread(path+label+"/"+filename)
        img_re = cv2.resize(img, (640,480))
        img_features = averagecolor(img_re)
        trainX.append(img_features)
        trainY.append(label)
    Test = (r"C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop/Banana_Ripeness-master/Data/Test")

img=cv2.imread(os.path.join('Database',filename))
#for img in os.path.join((Test):
for img in os.listdir(Test):
    test_img = cv2.imread(Test + img)
    test_img_feat = averagecolor(test_img)
    calculated_distances = []
    for i in trainX:
        calculated_distances.append(np.linalg.norm(test_img_feat-i))
    prediction = trainY[np.argmin(calculated_distances)]
    print(f"{img}:{prediction}")
```

**Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Rafael\Desktop\Banana_Ripeness-master\Banana_Ripeness(webcam).py", line 19, in  img_re = cv2.resize(img, (640,480)) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1i5nllza\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in**

*Using Opencv-python 4.5.4.58
Python 3.9

Comment: please provide full error [traceback](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-traceback/)

Comment: Please provide the full error message - this is only the part where it says what caused the error and what version of OpenCV you're using; the actual error should follow.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rafael\Desktop\Banana_Ripeness-master\Banana_Ripeness(webcam).py", line 19, in <module>
    img_re = cv2.resize(img, (640,480))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1i5nllza\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Comment: @rzlvmp i just update and included this info.

Comment: The file is non-existent.  Look at your actual path to the file and be sure it is correct. Try `test_img = cv2.imread(Test + "/" + img)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like here is bad files in your `os.listdir(path+label+"/")` folder

For example Windows caching images and creating [`thumbs.db`](https://kb.iu.edu/d/anha) hidden files.

1. Try to filter input files (check extension for example)
2. Use `try`→`except` to understand which `filename` is bad

```py
for filename in os.listdir(path+label+"/"):
    # check is file extension is an image
    if filename[-4:].lower() in ['.jpg', 'jpeg', '.bmp', '.png']:
        img = cv2.imread(path+label+"/"+filename)
        try:
            img_re = cv2.resize(img, (640,480))
        except:
            # print file name if some error happens
            print(f'BOOM! Bad file name is: {filename}')
            # re-raise same error
            raise
        img_features = averagecolor(img_re)
        trainX.append(img_features)
        trainY.append(label)
    else:
        # go to next file if not image
        continue
```